# Understanding the meaning of the "range" of outputs from a barchart

Tags: algebra-precalculus

> For the region in which the range of the dollar amounts of the four expense categories was least, what percent of total living expenses was the Transportation expense in that region?
>
> $$
> \text{A.}\; 10\%   
> \qquad
> \text{B.}\; 15\%
> \qquad
> \text{C.}\; 16\%   
> \qquad
> \text{D.}\; 17\%   
> \qquad
> \text{E.}\; 20\% 
> $$
>
> Below is the graph of living expenses for a typical household in selected regions April 2004
>   [image]

My answer is C because the range of that region is the least, 1000. But the answer turns out to be E, which means region $T$ satisfied the criteria mentioned in the problem. So I seem to have some misunderstanding of what the problem is actually asking for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The *range of the dollar amounts in a region* means something different than what you're thinking. In each region there are four living expenses that take on four different values (outputs). The *range* of the expenses is the difference between the most expensive thing and the least expensive thing in a given region. Calculating this for each region, it looks like region $T$ with an expense range of $50\% - 14\% = 36\%$, has the least range. And then the transportation expense in region $T$ is $20\%$.

Really though, we *should* calculate the range by looking at the difference in dollar amounts rather than percentages, since the outputs *are* dollar amounts. But then we'd have to estimate those dollar amounts from the graph and things'll get messy. This is an important distinction to make, because the *least range in terms of dollar amounts* might not match up with the *least range in terms of percentages.* (Challenge: come up with a barchart similar to the one above where this occurs). But I think the intent of the problem is to calculate the range with the percentages.